# CakePHP reverse routing: Html link not showing correct link

Tags: cakephp, routes, friendly-url

Firstly, I understand there have been many questions and solutions about this but none I've found fix my issue.

In summary, the Html helper is not reverse routing correctly and instead of URLs like this:

```
http://website.com/user_of_website/slug_name
```

I get URLs like this:

```
http://website.com/things/view/username:user_of_website/slug:a_thing
```

Here is my router setup:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
/**
* ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's urls.
*/
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

//User routes
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
Router::connect('/register', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));

Router::connect('/users/:action/*', array('controller' => 'users')); 
Router::connect('/things/:action/*', array('controller' => 'things')); 

Router::connect(
    '/:username/:slug',
    array(
        'controller' => 'things',
        'action' => 'view'
    ),array(
        'username' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_]+',
        'slug' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_]+',
        'pass'=>array(
            'username',
            'slug'
        )
    )
);
Router::connect('/:userName', array('controller' => 'things', 'action' => 'user'),array('pass'=>array('userName')));
```

And my Html helper:

```
echo $this->Html->link('View', array(
    'controller' => 'things',
    'action' => 'view',
    'username' => 'user_of_website',
    'slug' => 'a_thing'
),array(
    'class' => 'text-warning'
));
```

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

NB, I'm using CakePHP 2.3

Comment: Don't know if this affects your problem, but the last route (`/:userName`) uses a different notation  (camelcased) *and* does not contain a definition/regexp for the userName parameter

Comment: @thaJeztah, yeah I was testing something out, not related though. The issue was when I tested /username/slug links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried if it works if you disable the 'regular' routes for `things`? E.g. `/things/:action/*`.

My guess is that, because of the wildcard, this route will match the URL as well, and, because it is defined *before* your custom route, will be matched in stead.

If that resolves the problem, you may try to move that route *below* your 'custom' route

Comment: Thank-you, that does work. However any links going to /things/action were caught by the /:username/:slug rule. I've gotten around this by adding rules above it that only affect that action, e.g. /things/add
This is fine as there are only a few actions. I'll have to make sure I set up a robust username blacklist. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can also modify the 'username' Regexp so that controller-names are excluded. OR (possibly best?) put the custom Routes *below* the default CakePHP routes. This way CakePHP routes will be matched before using your routes